# Redirect URLs with FQDN (dot after TLD) to equivalent with PQDN

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, canonicalization, fqdn

Many websites can be accessed with a [FQDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name) (i.e., appending a dot to the TLD):

- https://www.ebay.com./
- https://www.google.com./
- https://www.reddit.com./
- https://stackoverflow.com./
- https://en.wikipedia.org./wiki/Main_Page

Some sites can’t be accessed that way, but I can’t find an example right now.¹ ²

**Is it possible, within a `.htaccess` file, to redirect all variants with the dot suffix to the variants without?**

Ideally with a "wildcard" rule, so that you don’t have to list the domains explicitly (for using it on different sites/domains without editing).

Example redirects:

- `http://example.com./` →
  `http://example.com/`
- `http://example.com./foo` →
  `http://example.com/foo`
- `http://sub.example.com./bar.html` →
  `http://sub.example.com/bar.html`

---

¹ stackoverflow.com, when accessed over HTTP, used to give HTTP error 400: "Bad Request - Invalid Hostname".

² Wikipedia, when accessed over HTTPS (when it was still optional), used to give a certificate error: "The certificate is only valid for the following names: `*.wikipedia.org` , `wikipedia.org` (Error code: ssl_error_bad_cert_domain)

Answer (score 1):

This should work :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9\.-]+)\.com\.$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.domain.com/$1  [QSA,L,R=301]
```