# What does ".." mean in url?

Tags: url, dns

I was doing some tests on my server and I found that adding `.` or `..` at the end of the URL seems to change things, but I don't know why.

It's not limited to my server, though. I can access `www.google.fr..` via Firefox or wget (didn't try an other mean, but I guess it's the same).

So, do you guys know what do these extra `.` mean?

Comment: http://www.dns-sd.org/TrailingDotsInDomainNames.html

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13309854/1591669

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two type of URL possible.

1. Absolute= having fully qualified path
2. Relative= having path relative to current directory.

**"."** & **".."** are used in relative paths.

**"."** means **Current Directory** or **Current Path Segment**

**".."** means **one directory up relative to current Directory/Current Path Segment**

Comment: Concerning your terminology, "directory" seems inappropriate in this context: A URL does not necessarily map to a hierarchical file system. A more appropriate term might be "path segment"; see e.g. [RFC 1808](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1808.txt).

Comment: @stakx ,I agree, updated answer above. But RFC 1808 doesn't states that too. :)

Comment: `.` and `..` can also occur in absolute URLs, e.g., `http://www.foo.com/bla/blub` is the same as `http://www.foo.com/bla/../bla/./blub`